# a simple probability code in matlab

Tags: math, matlab

I've written a basic code for probablity of some data.It works and gives me outputs, what I want to get.

```
A=[2 3 5 4 4 4 5 2 3 2 3]
    a=length(A);
    b=unique(A);
    for i=1:length(b)
        T(i)=sum(A(:)==b(i));
        prob(i)=T(i)./a;

    end
```

I can't understand how to use this code as a function. I saved the following code as M-file and called as prob(A) for any matrix, but it doesn't work. Could you please tell me my mistake?

```
function z=prob(A)
a=length(A);
b=unique(A);
for i=1:length(b)
    T(i)=sum(A(:)==b(i));
    pr(i)=T(i)./a;
    z=pr(i);
end
return
    end
```

Comment: If A is allowed to be a matrix, I'd be careful using length(A) to get number of elements. Either use [rows colms]=size(A);a=rows*colms. Or, a = length(A(:))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to specify your output variables.
Here I guess you want to output `pr`.

So you need to specify it in your first line:

```
function [pr]=prob(A)
```

and the complete function will be (you don't have to change anything here):

```
function [pr]=prob(A)
a=length(A);
b=unique(A);
for i=1:length(b)
    T(i)=sum(A(:)==b(i));
    pr(i)=T(i)./a;
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer:) I got it with your help...Here is it:'function [pr]=prob(A)
a=length(A);
b=unique(A);
for i=1:length(b)
    T(i)=sum(A(:)==b(i));
    pr(i)=T(i)./a;
end'

Answer (score 2):

This is how you return stuff from a matlab function:

```
 function [prob count] = calcProb(data, classNo)
   count = 0;
   rows = length(data);
   for i= 1:rows
      myValue=data(i);
      if(myValue == classNo) 
        count=count+1;
      end
   end

   prob = count/rows;
```

and its relevant call is

```
     [PC1 sampleC1]= calcProb(trainY, 0);
```

Comment: thanks a lot:) It was really helpfull to understand create a function!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the function name is the same as the file name (without the .m) in which the function is stored.

(Also note that you can omit the return in your function.)